# Client's BufferedReader not recieving line from Server, using sockets (Java)

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to make a chat application between a server and clients which are seperate classes. I'm not copying the whole code, but this is the part I'm not sure is set up correctly:

Server:

```
    ServerSocket s = null;
    Socket c = null;
    s = new ServerSocket(5002);

    c = s.accept();


    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()))
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(c.getOutputStream()));

    out.flush();
    String line;
    line = in.readLine();
    out.write("#W|Welcome");
    line = in.readLine();
    out.write("#W|Welcome");
    line = in.readLine();
    out.write("#W|Welcome");
```

Client :

```
    Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 5002);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream  ()));
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

    String line;
    out.flush();
    out.write("#J|test");
    line = in.readLine();
    out.write("#J|test");
    line = in.readLine();
```

After the client does `out.println()`, the server's `in.readLine()` gets the line. But when it's the other way around, the client keeps waiting at `in.readLine()`. (I used the debugger and watched the server execute `out.println()` and go past it, while the client is still stuck at `in.readLine()`.

Are my data streams set up correctly or is there probably an error in my code somewhere else? I'm not sure how to check in the debugger if the streams are connected correctly.

Comment: There is nothing here that either reads or writes lines, so it is impossible to answer your question. However, don't use `PrintWriter` over a network. It swallows exceptions. Use `BufferedWriter`, and don't forget to call `newLine()` as necessary.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I repeat. It swallows exceptions. See the Javadoc. I don't know what 'explicitly handles the `ErrorStream`' means.

Comment: Thank you. Too many beers...

Comment: I've changed to BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(c.getOutputStream())) on the servers's side, and it's still the same - client still doesn't recognize any incoming data from server, while the server does.

Comment: I've also edited my first post, so you can see what exactly I am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Quoting my comment above:]

> There is nothing here that [reads or] writes lines.

That remains true. All you have is:

```
out.write("#W|Welcome");
```

etc.

> don't forget to call newLine() as necessary

You forgot.

Comment: Added the new lines and called flush after, now it works. Thanks :).